# Swift changes colour of image when loaded

Tags: swift, uiimage, uikit, swift-playground

I have a swift playground in Xcode 7.3.1 and I am trying to load in this image [image: Mouth] into my program using `let mouth = UIImage(named: "happy-mouth")`. When the program runs the swift compiler returns the image like this...

[image]

Why does the swift playground change the colour of the image to a maroon colour instead of a peach colour?

Things I have tried

- Checking that the name of the image is "happy-mouth.png"
- Checking that the image is under my resources folder in swift
- Restarting Xcode
- Googling my issue and searching for it on StackOverflow

Comment: It could be that the image is transparent? What if you add it to a UIImageView and set the background color to white?

Comment: Thanks, I just realised that the image was partly transparent, silly me, I should of checked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common issue with transparent images. As they are usually shown in a `UIImageView` which inherits the background color from its parent view (superview) which is usually white, you don't get to notice that.

Instead of modifying the image, put it in a `UIImageView` and set the background color (of the `UIImageView`) to white.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is most likely that the image you have is partly transparent, because of that it mixes with the dark colour behind it changing the way it appears compared to how it appears on a white background. To fix this go back into your image editor (e.g. sketch, photoshop, illustrator) and make the colour opaque.

Comment: I believe it's better to change this in Xcode (via `UImageView`'s background color) and leave the image as it is.

Comment: It is defiantly a good idea however for what I'm doing it isn't really practical. I'm using a UIGraphicsImageContext to create one image from multiple images.